# Padding or margin for UILabels in UIStackView

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I want to add margins or paddings on the right of some nested UILabels

[image: View hierarchy]

like shown here:

[image: Target layout]

Using trailing spaces on the labels seems wrong and old-school somehow.

Any way to make that more elegant on interface builder?

Answer (score 34):

Just add a spacer view at the end of the horizontal stack view. Set its color to clear. Give it a width constraint to fix its size.

Or, judging from your screen shot, it looks like you could just move the right edge of the top-level stack view (child of MasterCell) to leave a margin.

#### UPDATE

You can set layout margins on a stack view, in the Size inspector:

[image: layout margins]

Maybe you just want to set the right layout margin.

If you set the stack view's layout margins in code (the `layoutMargins` property), you must also set its `layoutMarginsRelativeArrangement` property to `YES`.

Comment: I have been searching high and low to figure this out. Thanks for the updated answer. Why that Layout Margins is collapsed by default is a mystery, but I didn't see it until reading this post. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 8.2, but its getting crash. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: I faced collapsing bottom AutoLayout margin when hiding the last (at very bottom) view in the stack, setting fixed margins helped

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it forces the left - right choice on you, not leading - trailing.